# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException "Beans" must be followed by attribute specifications

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do a simple app with Spring. Once I start it I get an exception org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException
In detail: The error I am getting is this:

```
oct. 02, 2016 1:03:17 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
Infos: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@12bf892: startup date [Sun Oct 02 13:03:17 WAT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
oct. 02, 2016 1:03:17 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
Infos: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [SpringCanfig.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 37 in XML document from class path resource [SpringCanfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 13; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a : Contenu non valide trouvé à partir de l'élément 'List'. L'une des valeurs '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":meta, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":idref, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":value, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":null, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":array, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":list, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":set, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":map, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":props, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' est attendue.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at springcore.TestSpringProject.main(TestSpringProject.java:10)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 37; columnNumber: 13; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a : Contenu non valide trouvé à partir de l'élément 'List'. L'une des valeurs '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":meta, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":idref, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":value, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":null, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":array, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":list, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":set, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":map, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":props, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' est attendue.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:453)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3232)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1791)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

SpringCanfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!--test 1 <bean id="restarantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
    <property  name="welcomeNote" value="Welcome to our Restaruant!"></property>
</bean>-->

<!--test 2 -->
<!--<bean id="restarantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
    <constructor-arg ref="teaBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="teaBean" class="springcore.Tea"></bean>

</beans>-->

<!--test 3-->
<!--<bean id="restarantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
    <property name="hotDrink" ref="teaBean"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="teaBean" class="springcore.Tea"></bean>-->

<!--test 4-->
<bean id="restarantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
   <property name="restarantWaitersList">
      <List>
        <value>Mr. ABC</value>
        <value>Mr. BCD</value>
        <value>Mr. DEF</value>
        <value>Mr. GEF</value>
    </List>
   </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

after changing

```
<List>
            <value>Mr. ABC</value>
            <value>Mr. BCD</value>
            <value>Mr. DEF</value>
            <value>Mr. GEF</value>
        </List>
```

to

```
 <list>
            <value>Mr. ABC</value>
            <value>Mr. BCD</value>
            <value>Mr. DEF</value>
            <value>Mr. GEF</value>
        </list>
```

im getting this error:

```
oct. 02, 2016 3:26:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
Infos: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@12bf892: startup date [Sun Oct 02 15:26:51 WAT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
oct. 02, 2016 3:26:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
Infos: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [SpringCanfig.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from class path resource [SpringCanfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 18; Le type d'élément "beans" doit être suivi des spécifications d'attribut, ">" ou "/>".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at springcore.TestSpringProject.main(TestSpringProject.java:10)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 18; Le type d'élément "beans" doit être suivi des spécifications d'attribut, ">" ou "/>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.seekCloseOfStartTag(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1354)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:261)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: i need help pls

Comment: Reading the error message, it seems changing `<List>` to `<list>` (and similarly for the closing tags) should help.  Does it?

Comment: after changing <List> to <list> im getting error at Line 6  column 18 in XML

Comment: And what was that error?  Edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: i can find a solution

Comment: That error says your Spring beans file isn't well-formed XML.  When making your previous change you must have (accidentally, perhaps) made some other change to your XML file.  Is there a `>` at the end of the `<beans ...` tag?

Comment: ty i fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
     xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"> 

<!--test 1 <bean id="restaruantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
    <property  name="welcomeNote" value="Welcome to our Restaruant!"></property>
</bean>-->

<!--test 2 -->
<!--<bean id="restaruantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
    <constructor-arg ref="teaBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="teaBean" class="springcore.Tea"></bean>

</beans>-->

<!--test 3-->
<!--<bean id="restaruantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
    <property name="hotDrink" ref="teaBean"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="teaBean" class="springcore.Tea"></bean>-->

<!--test 4-->
<bean id="restaruantBean" class="springcore.Restaruant">
   <property name="restaruantWaitersList">
      <list>
        <value>Mr. ABC</value>
        <value>Mr. BCD</value>
        <value>Mr. DEF</value>
        <value>Mr. GEF</value>
    </list>
   </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```